# How to Handle NULL Values in H2 CSVREAD?

Tags: java, csv, h2, in-memory-database

I'm in the process of trying to populate an in-memory H2 database for use in testing. I'm currently using groovy to create the database with the statement:

```
create table Customer_V (
   "Company" nvarchar(30)  NULL , 
   "No" nvarchar(20)  NULL , 
   "DW_Batch" bigint  NULL  );
```

That seemed to work fine, I was able to write some data and the query the contents. The problem I'm running into is that I want to use CSVREAD to batch upload my test data. I created a csv file like this:

```
Company,No,DW_Batch
"TURA, US - LIVE",111309,NULL
"TURA, US - LIVE",211226,NULL
```

and uploaded it in groovy with:

```
String populateCustomer = """insert into Customer_V select * from CSVREAD('src/test/resources/nav_customers.csv')"""
sql.executeInsert(populateCustomer);
```

When the statement tries to execute it fails with the error

> Failed to execute: insert into Customer_V select * from
> CSVREAD('src/test/resources/nav_customers.csv') because: Data
> conversion error converting "'NULL' (CUSTOMER_V: ""DW_Batch""
> BIGINT)";

I'm not quite sure what the problem is here. Is there something special I have to do to tell H2 that I want a NULL value rather than a literal 'Null' string?

Comment: Instead of *"TURA, US - LIVE",111309,NULL* try `"TURA, US - LIVE",111309,` (note trailing comma)

Comment: @g00se That does seem to work, but I'm not sure why. Other data types are able to handle NULL in the CSV without throwing an error. For example, if I change the csv to "TURA, US - LIVE",NULL,111309 it will convert the NULL to nvarchar with no complaints.

Comment: You'd have to look at the driver docs/code to see exactly why, I'd think